# On sums of quadratic residues

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p>3$ be a prime.
We set $R=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}: (x/p)=1\}$, where $(\cdot/p)$ is the Legendre symbol. When $p\equiv3\pmod4$, by class formulae of imaginary quadratic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, we can easily obtain that
$$A_p:=\sum_{0<x<p/2,x\in R}x=(p^2-1)/16,\ \text{if}\ p\equiv7\pmod8,$$
and that
$$A_p=\sum_{0<x<p/2,x\in R}x=(p^2-1+8ph(-p))/16,\ \text{if}\ p\equiv3\pmod8,$$
where $h(-p)$ is the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$. However, in the case $p\equiv1\pmod4$
I can not get the explicit value of $$A_p=\sum_{0<x<p/2,x\in R}x.$$

Your comments are welcome.

Comment: Amazingly, the sequence $A_p$ is not in the OEIS.

Comment: @Seva The search http://oeis.org/search?q=sums+of+quadratic+residues&language=english&go=Search brings up a certain number of sequences though. Maybe it is the summation below p/2 that makes the difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By standard formulas for values of L functions at negative integers, for
$p\equiv1\pmod4$ one has
$$A_p=(p^2-1)/16+aL(\chi_p,-1)\;,$$
with $a=3/4$ if $p\equiv1\pmod8$ and $a=5/4$ if $p\equiv5\pmod8$
where $\chi_p(x)=(x/p)$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.